How do I extract part of a string data from a specific column in pandas?
I have a dataframe where I want to create a new column to inform the state of a given institution - df['ict_state']. This information is provided in another column of the dataframe - df['ict_name'], that comes with more info as a string type. Normally, the information I want is right after the first '-' of the string. So to get exactly the info about state there's some treatment to be made.
Example: If the cell contains the string 'ict1 - rio - laboratorio nuclear' the new column get the string 'rio'. If the cell contains the string 'ict2 - bsb' the new column get the string 'bsb'. If the cell contains the string 'ict3' new column get the string 'nan'.
I tried to apply a for loop in a specific column to transform the string of the cell in a list and get the second element of that list.
Example:
matrix_entrada = [
    (1, 'ictX'),
    (2, 'ict - rio - estudos nucleares'),
    (3, 'ict - ba - laboratorio IA'),
    (4, 'ict132 - sp')]
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix_entrada, columns=['id', 'ict_name'])

for ict in df['ict_name']:
    if len(ict.split('-')) > 1:
        df['ict_state'] = ict.split('-')[1]
    else:
        df['ict_state'] = 'nan'

df

Output:
    id  ict_name                       ict_state
0   1   ictX                           sp
1   2   ict - rio - estudos nucleares  sp
2   3   ict - ba - laboratorio IA      sp
3   4   ict132 - sp                    sp

Expected output:
    id  ict_name                       ict_state
0   1   ictX                           nan
1   2   ict - rio - estudos nucleares  rio
2   3   ict - ba - laboratorio IA      ba
3   4   ict132 - sp                    sp

What am I doing wrong?

regex
Use a regex and str.extract:
df['ict_state'] = df['ict_name'].str.extract(r'-\s*(\S+)')

Output:
   id                       ict_name ict_state
0   1                           ictX       NaN
1   2  ict - rio - estudos nucleares       rio
2   3      ict - ba - laboratorio IA        ba
3   4                    ict132 - sp        sp

Regex:
-        # match literal "-"
\s*      # match 0 or more spaces
(\S+)    # capture one or more non-space characters

regex demo
If you really want the 'nan' string for no match, fillna:
df['ict_state'] = (df['ict_name'].str.extract(r'-\s*(\S+)')
                   .fillna('nan')
                  )

Output:
   id                       ict_name ict_state
0   1                           ictX       nan
1   2  ict - rio - estudos nucleares       rio
2   3      ict - ba - laboratorio IA        ba
3   4                    ict132 - sp        sp

python operations
You can also use pure python operations, which is most of the time faster than pandas if you have more than 2/3 operations (rule of thumb):
df['ict_state'] = [l[1].strip() if len(l:=s.split('-', 2))>1 else 'nan'
                   for s in df['ict_name']]

Or with a custom function:
def get_word(s):
    l = s.split('-', 2)
    return l[1].strip() if len(l)>1 else 'nan'

df['ict_state'] = df['ict_name'].map(get_word)

Output:
   id                       ict_name ict_state
0   1                           ictX       nan
1   2  ict - rio - estudos nucleares       rio
2   3      ict - ba - laboratorio IA        ba
3   4                    ict132 - sp        sp

timings
timing of the approaches in this answer and df['ict_name'].str.split('-').str[1].str.strip() from @wjandrea's answer (chained_pandas_str):


The problem is that you're assigning to the whole column, not the cell.
Instead you could use:
Vectorized string methods
>>> df['ict_name'].str.split('-').str[1].str.strip()
0    NaN
1    rio
2     ba
3     sp
Name: ict_name, dtype: object


You might want to add n=2 to .str.split() to only split twice at most.
I added .str.strip() to remove leading/trailing whitespace

Regex in .str.extract()
>>> df['ict_name'].str.extract(r'-\s*(.*?)(?:\s*-|$)', expand=False)
0    NaN
1    rio
2     ba
3     sp
Name: ict_name, dtype: object

(same result)
Breakdown:

\s* - Zero or more whitespace
.*? - Anything, non-greedy
(?:...) - Non-matching group
-|$ - Either hyphen or end of line
expand=False - Make result Series (i.e. the regex returns a scalar)


This result contains a real NaN. If you really do want the string 'nan', use .fillna():
>>> _.fillna('nan')
0    nan
1    rio
2     ba
3     sp
Name: ict_name, dtype: object


Chaining more than 2/3 str operations is usually less efficient than using pure python (is as slow as the regex). I added a timing

@mozway I just realized it could be .str.split(' - ') instead, then you don't need the strip. How does that compare? I imagine it's about the same, but I'd still like to know.

@mozway I know they can be slow, but I like the convenience of automatically handling missing values, though in a chain, I suppose the check for missing values happens at each step, redundantly.

It doesn't change much the speed. I fully agree regarding the convenience, it's quite nice, but I also like to know the limitations ;)
